# Implementing multiple layout for multiple screens but not working in android studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-studio-2.1

I am new to android developer. I designed the multiple layouts for multiple screens but the layouts are not working in android studio.
I use different layout folders:

layout-small,
layout-normal,
layout-large,
layout-xlarge,
layout(default)

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I tested in small mobiles image view not resized  text only changed in sometimes . large mobile  rendering the default layout like samsung galaxy tab(SM-T23Nu)

Answer (score 0):

What you **should** do is scale everything on your screen as per screen size.
eg: If you have a textView, you can do:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView_ID);
int tempSize = myTextView.getTextSize();
myTextView.setSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tempSize*w*h/KONSTANT);
```

Where w and h are the width and height of the screen and KONSTANT is the product of your default screen size.
You can get w and h by using:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    h = metrics.heightPixels;
    w = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Alternatively, what you can do is have multiple layouts (as you're currently doing) and then choose one according to screen size.
eg:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    h = metrics.heightPixels;
    w = metrics.widthPixels;

    if (h == smallScreenH && w == smallScreenW) {
        setContentView(R.layout.small_screeen);
    }
    else if (h == mediumScreenH && w == mediumScreenH) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mdeium_screen);
    }
}
```